# Explanation of proof of Radius of convergence of the derivative of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, power-series

The derivative of a power series $\sum a_nx^n$ is given as

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) a_{n+1}x^n$$

and it is known that the radius of convergence of the derivative is the same as the original.

The justification in my course notes was as follows:

$$ \limsup |(n+1)a_{n+1}|^{1/n} = \lim (n+1)^{1/n} \limsup |a_n|^{1/(n-1)} = \limsup |a_n|^{1/n}.$$

I'm confused on the algebra in the first equality (breaking up the $\limsup$) - could anyone explain that part?

Comment: It is one of the properties of $\limsup$: $\limsup a_nb_n = \lim a_n\cdot \limsup b_n$ provided $\lim a_n$ and $\limsup b_n$ exists and is not of the form $0\cdot\infty$. Also, possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761307/the-derivative-of-a-power-series-has-the-same-radius-of-convergence

Comment: (In other words, one of the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ must be bounded in addition to the $\lim$s/$\operatorname{lim\ sup}$s existing.)